# Modal window gets hidden behind header?

Tags: jquery, html, css, modal-dialog

So I've implemented a modal window jQuery plugin called "Reveal" for a 'Size Guide' window I've added to my bigcartel site **(it isn't done yet so please do not try buying anything, button is open for testing purposes)**  If you're scrolled up at least a little bit or all the way up, and click the 'SIZE GUIDE' button, the modal window pops up and gets hidden behind the header.

If you were to scroll down enough and click the 'SIZE GUIDE' button, the modal window also gets hidden behind the 'YOU MAY ALSO LIKE...' section as well. **In other words, the modal window only likes to show up in the 'gray background' area.**

I've tried z-index properties but nothing is working.

**The modal window CSS for just the modal window alone looks like this:**

```
.reveal-modal {
    visibility: hidden;
    top: -200px; 
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -320px;
    width: 585px;
    background: #fff url(modal-gloss.png) no-repeat -200px -80px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 101;
    padding: 30px 40px 34px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    -box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    }
```

**Here is where I got the Reveal modal window:**
http://zurb.com/playground/reveal-modal-plugin

To summarize this, my overall question is, how do I have the modal box pop up in not just the gray background area, but show up over the header and 'you may also like...' section? Because they're currently hiding behind the header and (if you scroll down far enough and click the 'SIZE GUIDE' button) the 'you may also like...' section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem seems to be this declaration here:

```
div#content.strip {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

content contains the modal and so it is hiding the "overflow."  If you can't remove or re-work that style, you may want to move your modal outside of content wrapper.

Comment: Alright that worked, but now my gray background won't work (which was a problem I had before adding the overflow:hidden; property) Any way I can get the background working again?

Comment: I updated my answer to add "If you can't remove or re-work that style, you may want to move your modal outside of content wrapper."

Comment: I hope you don't mind answering this question too. So the link that says 'hey' next to my ADD TO BAG button is where I want the "SIZE GUIDE" button to appear, but it goes to the next line (where the SIZE GUIDE button currently is haha) how can I get it to show up where the 'hey' link is?

Comment: @kdm Looking at your url, it looks like you figured it out. The "hey" link that is.

Comment: Yeah I got it! Thanks though :)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you meant (hopefully) is that the Model box is **positioned** to one part of the screen and doesn't stay in front of users screen as they scroll?

**If that's the case try this:**

```
.reveal-modal {
visibility: hidden;
top: -200px; 
left: 50%;
margin-left: -320px;
width: 585px;
background: #fff url(modal-gloss.png) no-repeat -200px -80px;
position: fixed;
z-index: 101;
padding: 30px 40px 34px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
```

Comment: Nono haha. I wanted it like that. What I mean is, if you were to have your window scrolled all the way up, and click the 'SIZE GUIDE' button, some of it hides behind the header.